# Jquery traversing to child elements

Tags: jquery

I am stuck in traversing in the jquery.

when i console.log($('image')); i will get as follows

```
<div class="product-img-box" id="image">
    <div id="wrap" style="top:0px;z-index:1;position:relative;"><a href="mydomain.com/media/catalog/product/c/e/ceramic_straightner_-_s3_red_black_1_1.jpg" class="cloud-zoom" id="zoom" rel="zoomWidth:'330', zoomHeight:'330', position:'right', adjustX:0, adjustY:0, lensOpacity:0.5, smoothMove:3, showTitle:'true', titleOpacity:0.5" style="position: relative; display: block;">
        <img src="mydomain.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/550x550/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/e/ceramic_straightner_-_s3_red_black_1_1.jpg" alt="Ceramic Straightner" style="width: 550px; display: block;" title="">
        </a><div class="mousetrap" style="z-index: 999; position: absolute; width: 456px; height: 456px; left: 0px; top: 0px; cursor: move; background-image: url(mydomain.com/index.php/straighteners/);"></div></div>
    </div>
```

I am trying to traverse to the img tag.how can i access.

Comment: `console.log($('image'));` or `console.log($('#image'));`

Comment: use jquery `find` method.

Comment: You can use `console.log($('#image img'));`

Comment: console.log($('image'))

Answer (score 1):

You want the `img` element selector

```
$('img')
```

or

```
$('#image img')
```

```js
console.log($('#image img'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-img-box" id="image">
    <div id="wrap" style="top:0px;z-index:1;position:relative;"><a href="mydomain.com/media/catalog/product/c/e/ceramic_straightner_-_s3_red_black_1_1.jpg" class="cloud-zoom" id="zoom" rel="zoomWidth:'330', zoomHeight:'330', position:'right', adjustX:0, adjustY:0, lensOpacity:0.5, smoothMove:3, showTitle:'true', titleOpacity:0.5" style="position: relative; display: block;">
        <img src="mydomain.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/550x550/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/c/e/ceramic_straightner_-_s3_red_black_1_1.jpg" alt="Ceramic Straightner" style="width: 550px; display: block;" title="">
        </a><div class="mousetrap" style="z-index: 999; position: absolute; width: 456px; height: 456px; left: 0px; top: 0px; cursor: move; background-image: url(mydomain.com/index.php/straighteners/);"></div></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: no its $('image') only.returing html on console.log with $('image')

Comment: @PradeepSanku, see my code snippet. It is working. Let me know if you meant something else

Comment: am using jquery zoom plugin in which the html has been assigend to $('image') thats why on console.log i m getting html

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$("#image").find("img");
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#image img");` or `$("#image").find("img");`

While usually the second one is faster, because it is converted to original Javascript code: `document.getElementById("image").getElementsByTagName("img");`.